# Installing Ubuntu on an internal hard drive, and removing completely to boot Windows from another internal HDD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hard-drive

I've seen a few posts about dual booting/partitioning and running Ubuntu from an EXTERNAL hard drive. What I want to decipher is whether it's possible to remove my laptops INTERNAL hard drive which contains windows and buy another INTERNAL HDD and install ubuntu on that? and then on the rare occasions i need to switch back to windows, I could completely remove the other internal HDD. I've read a lot about boot loaders etc, but would my laptop be able to boot into each system as they are on completely separate internal HDDs and would never be in the laptop at the same time.

Hopefully that makes sense, I'm assuming it's not great to regularly swap an internal HDD, but i just wanted to know if this is hypothetically possible?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

If u install Ubuntu in a separate HDD there wont be any problem with the bootloaders and you can switch back to windows as you mention